# Can I answer questions if I don't have complete knowledge about the topic?

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it okay if I answer any questions posted, even if I don't have complete knowledge about it?

Comment: This would be a very quiet site indeed if we required answerers to have *complete* knowledge of the topic. How do you even define that? Should a C question about how many parameters `scanf` supports only be answered by somebody who has complete knowledge about C (which is impossible) or complete knowledge about `scanf` (which is probably just as rare, actually)?

Comment: @Flimm if you think it is overly useful then make an edit so the question stands out. I can see it has some merit but I wouldn't call this a stellar question. I don't see why I should hold my votes based on the first revision

Answer (score 11):

You can. Some guidelines, from my personal experience, to help decide whether to post or not:

- Does what I want to say add any value to answers that may already exist? If what I'd like to post has already been said and I can't add anything new: **don't post**.
- Is what I want to add to the information already available in answers only an observation and/or a link to outside resources? According to site guidelines, this kind of information does not make up a complete answer. It could/should be written in a comment to the question. But comments can only be posted if a user has >= 50 rep points. If that applies to me: **don't post**.
- Is my information "anecdotal", describing my experiences with the same problem? If I don't have a solution, then: **don't post** (unless, *perhaps*, as a comment).
- (Continuing from the previous point) If I found a solution, I make sure I write the solution as one of the first things, and any description about my experience later. This way the answer part is easily recognizable. So: **Yes, post**.
- Do I have a solution that I've been able to test and works? Then **yes, post**. But I always try to add some explanation about *why* what I post answers the question / how it works. This helps the person asking (and others who find the information in the future) better understand and learn. Answers that are only "Try this" with some code are not the best quality.

Comment: If only we put this answer text instead of the "Post Your Answer" text on answer button...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, if you can convince TPTB I'd be more than happy for them to use it :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can. But there is the risk that you will post a low quality answer. Low quality answers don't help the question asker. They also attract downvotes. If your posts often receive downvotes you could be banned from posting.

Comment: Seriously? This happens? ;)  Seeing some answers which are outright dangerous, I somehow doubt that...

Comment: It does happen. The problem is that upvotes often swamp downvotes, and a lot of the upvotes come from people who don't have enough knowledge to know that the answer is correct.  That's why we often see incorrect or even dangerous answers with a large number of net upvotes.